# Laravel 5 - view('test') in controllers not working as expect

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am new in Laravel. I read documentation and googling but I can't find answer for my problem.

Im trying to render a simple view test.blade.php (located at resources/views).

a) first try:
 in app/Http/routes.php I wrote

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('test');
});
```

It's working. Hurray! I see my simple site

b) second try:
 in app/Http/routes.php i wrote

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

I have created a controller WelcomeController.php in app/Http/Controllers 
 Inside controller I wrote:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('test');
    }
}
```

And....this is not working, I see only blank page. 
   Ok I was digging and digging and trying to understand what's the problem.
   I changed retun view('test') to return view()->make('test'); but this is not working too - it generates only blank page....

Then I simply changed retun to echo: echo view('test');
It is working like charm.

What am I doing wrong? all examples in the internet shows return view('..') not echo view('...') (which is ugly)...

Please help me :)

Comment: just for testing try to write `dd("test");` before return `view('test');` see if comes with test text on the screen

Comment: Try to active debugging mode and see if it return specific error, It might be your WelcomeController has problem with classnaming

Comment: dd("test") produce "test" in browser.
and this is my .env:
APP_DEBUG=true

i have changed controller name to TestabcController (and of course routes.php to new controller name) and this is not working too

Comment: nice, can you activate debuggning mode to true, if you do not know how let me know

Comment: if there is other method to activate debug mode as i did (in file .env APP_DEBUG=true) please let me know

Comment: one way is via .env file and other one is name->app->app.php and set debug to true

Comment: Also check your logs for errors at storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: logs folder is empty - I gave permission for all 777 (I' know this not good idea but I did it only for testing)

Comment: it is fine doing any thing while testing just beware when moving to production to put everything proper again. but before looking in to log files, have you set debugging mode to true? if yes what do you get on your screen of errors?

Comment: btw how did you created WelcomeControlller

Comment: First what I did (before creating contorller and etc..) was turning on APP_DEBUG to true....and I think Debuging mode working, becouse any error in code like echo aaaa (without quotes) give nice error:

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
FatalErrorException in TestabcController.php line 15:
syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting ',' or ';'

So, debug mode is on, return view('test') giving blank page, echo view('test') give correct page 

i know this is strange....

Comment: Yes I have controler WelcomeController, I have test.blade.php and I have route for this controller and method.

Comment: What is this TestabcController.php?

Comment: I know you have WelcomeController but how did you created that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93903/discussion-between-maytham-mahiam-and-krzysztof-chelchowski).

Comment: I change the name of WelcomeController to TestabcController for mement to se is there any class naming problem as you said. But know is as at the begining: WelcomeController

I created cotntroller by php artisan make:controller WelcomeController

Comment: Instead of returning the view just add echo 'Hello'; die; inside the index function.. Comment the return view('test') line for a moment

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of digging I got it!

I decided to create second project and using composer to install laravel in another directory. Next I opened great tool names Meld which I used to compare these two installations. I noticed that there are some diferences in main controller Controller.php located at app/Http/Controllers

In my first installation (that with problems) it was:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public $auto_render = true;

    /**
     * Execute an action on the controller.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function callAction($method, $parameters)
    {
        parent::callAction($method, $parameters);
    }    
}
```

And in the second installation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

I decided to remove callAction from Controller.php because it only call parent method. Then I checked my page in browser...and

Hurrrayy it's working....return view('test') working as it should...

I think, that in some previous version of Laravel this method was added, and in the next someone removed it...but why it blocks rendering template?

It happens because overwritten function did not return result...
When I changed that function like this:

```
public function callAction($method, $parameters)
{
    return parent::callAction($method, $parameters);
}
```

That was the solution! Everything is now working great.

I want to thank you all, a specially maytham-mahiam and revo for your big help.

Answer (score 0):

***Another approach is routes definition using array***

Try this:

You could also specify the controller and action within array.

Here we are saying the route to use the ***index*** function within the ***WelcomeController***

Add in ***routes.php***

```
Route::get('/', [ 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@index' ]);
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I have been talking to OP this is not the problem he is working on it after a long chat